# How to pass data from one page to another in jquery mobile without using query string?

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to pass data from one page to another in jquery mobile without using query string?
is it possible to use dom to pass data can any one help me out..
i have employee id in page1 on click of submit button the page navigates to page2 in page2 i have a dropdown it should be filled in page load,,before the pageshow i should pass the value of employee id as a input to the population of dropdown and without using query string or local storage..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use PHP and create a SESSION variable or POST variable for the employee ID? The variable will be destroyed when they close their browser.